# MySQL, count values by key

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to count values on a table accordingly with their presence or missing.

With a clear example consider a table with 2 field:

```
+-------+---------+
| K     | V       |
+-------+---------+
| key1  | 10      |
| key1  | 20      |
| key1  | Stefano |
| key1  | 40      |
| key1  | 50      |
| key1  | 60      |
| key1  | Stefano |
| key1  | 80      |
| key1  | 90      |
| key1  | 100     |
| key1  | 110     |
+-------+---------+
| key2  | 11      |
| key2  | 21      |
| key2  | 31      |
| key2  | Stefano |
| key2  | 51      |
| key2  | 61      |
| key2  | 71      |
| key2  | 81      |
| key2  | 91      |
| key2  | 101     |
+-------+---------+
| key3  | 13      |
| key3  | 23      |
| key3  | 33      |
+-------+---------+
```

My goal is count occurrences of V = 'Stefano' getting -1 if K is not existing:

```
select count(*) from TableName where K = 'key1' and V = 'Stefano'
> 2

select count(*) from TableName where K = 'key2' and V = 'Stefano'
> 1

select count(*) from TableName where K = 'key3' and V = 'Stefano'
> 0
```

How I can get value [ -1 ] querying on a missing key value?

```
select count(*) from TableName where K = 'missing_key' and V = 'Stefano'
> -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems silly that you would want `-1` rather than `0`, but one method is:

```
select coalesce(nullif(count(*), 0), -1)
from TableName
where K = 'missing_key' and V = 'Stefano';
```

If you wanted a special non-0 value, I would suggest `NULL`.

Note:  You can do this all in a single query:

```
select k, sum( v = 'Stefano' )
from tablename
group by k;
```

You can use the `coalesce(nullif())` logic here too.

EDIT:

If you only want -1 when the key is missing, then:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then -1
             else sum(v = 'Stefano')
        end)
from TableName
where K = 'missing_key';
```

Comment: I think that you have misread the question. OP wants -1 only when supplied key is not present in the table. It's a different scenario from key being in the table but with no 'Stefano'.

Comment: I was writing a simple CASE when I realized that